# Error when trying to do string var = "\"

Tags: c#

I am trying to do a Path.Combine. One string is the path and the other is just a slash.

```
string ok = browser.SelectedPath;
            string okie = "\";
            string pathy = Path.Combine(ok, okie);
            Settings.Default["Path"] = pathy;
```

for

```
string okie = "\";
```

I get two errors  NewLine in constant. Anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: use two backslash `"\\"`.

Comment: "\\" . Backslash is an escape character so need to double it for the backslash character

Comment: Now all I get is a slash when I do combine. It does not include string ok. What do i do? String Ok comes from a FolderBrowserDialog

Comment: What is contained in the string `ok`?

Comment: I select a folder and it gives its path in string.

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of okie and pathy, and assign Settings.Default["Path"] the browser.SelectedPath, eg

`Settings.Default["Path"] = browser.SelectedPath;`

Comment: I need a slash afterwards to allow me a save a file.

Comment: So do a concatenate `ok += "\\";` your using Path.Combine wrong, use it only to combine directory paths.

Comment: It worked thank you!

Comment: Do yourself a favour and watch a few debugging tutorials and learn to use the keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Use Path.Combine to add the file name to the directory path. If you're concatenating the file name on the end, you're missing the point of path.combine and also opening up potential security or crash bugs in your program.

Comment: Also, if this is on Windows (which I'm guessing it is due to the back slash separators) if the user selects the root of the hard disk, the value will be "C:\", which the above concatenation will add an extra '\' on the end. As dodexahedron says, don't worry about putting the '\' on the end, just make sure you use `Path.Combine` when you want to append a file or relative path on the end.

Comment: Guys, I only put `browser.SelectedPath;` I don't get the answer downvote? `you didn't downvote me for the combine directories comment?